# How to properly reference JRE in Maven?

Tags: maven, java

In our application, we're going to package the JRE as an embedded DLL (to avoid typical Windows issue).

As our project is a typical Maven citizen, I would like to include that JRE as a Maven dependency, to use it later. But is there such an artifact available? And if not, what could be the preferred way to package it?

- zipping the whole JRE folder and uploading it to our Nexus?
- use a "magical" artifact?
- any other solution?

Comment: "I would like to include that JRE as a maven dependency" and how can you than download this JRE. As I know Maven required installed JRE on computer. so I don't understand profit of this feature. May be the better idea set in pom configuration version of jre or jdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was already touched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540454/jre-1-6-in-maven-repository-public-or-private)

Also if you are on Linux, then you can use RPM solution for application/server, but it is the solution more for deployment and not development.