# Maven - Download Files/Folders

Tags: maven, download

I am searching for a Maven plug-in that would help me download project artifacts. For example, I've a remote location, with the following directory structure:

- Directory-A

  - Directory-B

    - artifact1.jar
    - artifact2.jar
  - Directory-C

    - artifact3.jar
    - artifact4.jar

All I want to do is when I specify Directory-A/Directory-B, it creates the structure locally and downloads all the artifacts from the remote location to the local structure.

Is that possible in Maven? The closest that I got is via [maven-download-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-download-plugin/), as suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741965/1168372). However, this plugin lets me download individual artifacts (or as far as I understood from the usage documentation).

Thoughts, ideas? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What would you like to achieve with this? Is this a kind of preparation for deployment (to application server or so)? Apart from that the artifacts will be downloaded automatically by maven if you define them as dependencies, but i assume that is not what we are talkting about.

Comment: @khmarbaise: you're right, this is not part of maven dependencies. These artifacts would basically be required as part of deployment. I want to download these artifacts and use them as part of the packaging structure that I'm building up