# How to deploy a Java project using war file on CloudControl

Tags: cloudcontrol

I have my Java project in a Hg repository.  How can I use this code or convert to Git repo to be able to deploy on Cloud Control?

Is there an Option for me to use a .war file to Deploy instead of the entire file structure upload and compile?  If so, would it matter if the war file was built using Tomcat server or Glass-fish server?

Your help in answering these question will be a valuable information for me.  Appreciate your help in advance.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep all mercurial branches, tags and history use [fast-export](https://github.com/frej/fast-export). Otherwise just create git repository from scratch:

```
git init; git add . ; git commit -am "Initial commit"
```

Deploying prebuilt war file is not the recommended way. You should [push](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#version-control--images) to the repository (via git or [cctrlapp](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#command-line-client-web-console-and-api)) and let cloudControl platform take care of the build process. Anyway you can still use Maven to download the war file. You can find some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741806/maven-downloading-files-from-url).

Apart from this you have to provide an embedded [jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Using_Jetty_Runner) or [tomcat](https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner) runner and specify start command in [Procfile](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#buildpacks-and-the-procfile):

Jetty:

```
web: java -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/YOU_WAR.war
```

Tomcat:

```
web: java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/YOUR_WAR.war
```

Keep in mind that war file should be built independently of any application servers.