# Maven checkstyle https configuration

Tags: java, maven, https, checkstyle

I have the following maven check style plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
        <configLocation>https://someUtl.com/file.xml</configLocation>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Pay attention on

```
<configLocation>https://someUtl.com/file.xml</configLocation>
```

file.xml can be downloaded by browser, but it require a login and password. Is there a way to specify these login/password in maven or in plugin configuration?

Answer (score 4):

Underneath, this uses [Plexus](http://plexus.codehaus.org/index.html) which in turn pretty much does `URL.openStream()`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java) shows how an `Authenticator` can be used for that in Java code, but I was unable to find a Maven equivalent for that. I'm inclined to say that it's not possible.

Alternatively, you might be able to download the file in a separate mojo execution, then point the `configLocation` to the downloaded file, which could be anywhere down your `target` folder.

I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741806/maven-downloading-files-from-url) gives a few nice ideas about how to download files in Maven. Their first is that if your file is a Maven artifact, you could use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/).

And then we come full circle, because if your Checkstyle configuration were to be contained in a Maven artifact, you would not have to set `configLocation` to a remote location, but you'd add that artifact as a `dependency` of your Checkstyle plugin execution. Since Maven defines everything in terms of dependencies, that is my way to go, and that is exactly how I set up my own Checkstyle configurations.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.totaalsoftware.incidentmanager</groupId>
        <artifactId>checkstyle-config</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <configLocation>checkstyle.config.xml</configLocation>
      ...
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Clearly, in the above example, `checkstyle.config.xml` resides in the root of the `checkstyle-config` JAR.