# Is there a command-line java tool like wget/curl?

Tags: java, ant, maven-3

I want to write a `ant/maven` script to download and install some of the internal applications.

I am looking for tool which can give functionality like `wget` or `curl` so that I can directly call that from ant/maven it should support multiple protocols like `https`, `ftp`, `http`.

I expect there could be tool by `Apache` but not getting it.

Does `http://hc.apache.org/` works as wget/curl I want all the verification like `ssl` certificate verification and all.

Comment: http://pipasoft.com/free-java-classes/download/wget.java. http://wget-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/wgetJava/edu/depauw/csc/dcheeseman/wgetjava/WGETJava.java. Seriously, Google it.

Comment: Ant's [Get](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html)? [maven-download-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-download-plugin/) or [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html)?

Comment: Also, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2741806/205936) SO post.

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java as well as comments

Comment: @S.R.I Does ant `Get` command support HTTPS protocol. I tried it but not getting success.