# How to include remote folder in Maven war file as part of build?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

As part of maven build, I want the war file to include a file that is located on http. Is this possible?

The folder strcuture should look something like this

- META-INF
- WEB-INF
- ui.zip > This has to be pulled from an external resource located on web.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: downloading files from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741806/maven-downloading-files-from-url)

Comment: Put that file into a repository manager as any other dependency and you can add it as dependency which will be packaged.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741806/maven-downloading-files-from-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741806/maven-downloading-files-from-url)